# Why does this function loop forever?

Tags: c++, network-programming, winsock

I have this function that takes a `SOCKET`  and a file name to the output file, then it tries to receive and output the data to a file, when compiling and running the code it works fine but the program does not exit and the output file (`file.txt`) contains some unreadable garbage text

the rest of the code work fine and tested, I am sure the problem is in this file but can't tell what and where

```
int recv_file(SOCKET soc, const char * fname)
{
    FILE * ptr; 
    char buffer[MAX];
    unsigned long long int x = 0; 
    if (fopen_s(&ptr, fname , "wb") != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to receive file \n");
        return 1;
    }

    do
    {
        c = recv(soc, buffer, MAX, 0);
        printf("recv count : %d\n",c);
        // here was -> fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), ptr);
        fwrite(buffer, 1, c, ptr);
    }
    while ( c > 0);
    printf("Total received : %lld\n", x);

    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

as an output it prints only one line `recv count : 65`

I tried to use `closesocket(soc);WSACleanup();` but this does not solve the problem

for the server, I tested with netcat and python socketserver and had same behavior for both

also the last `printf` right after the `do-while` does not get printed to the screen

Comment: if (c <= 0)
            break;

Comment: `fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), ptr);` is outputting all of  the `buffer`.  You only what to output up to the amount read.

Comment: It should be `fwrite(buffer, 1, c, ptr);`

Comment: @MarekR explain please what is wrong with this

Comment: Please don't change the question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers. If you want to provide additional information and show modified code, then please add it to the bottom of the question instead of overwriting the original question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Data from network can come in chuncks
2. `recv` returns negative value on errors that what break handles (stops loop).
3. `recv` returns number of bytes received.
4. `fwrite` should write number of bytes equal to those which has been received, so it should be:

```c
fwrite(buffer, 1, c, ptr);
```

Passing there `sizeof(buff)` will record trash in a file (content form previous read or memory trash).

Now question is what sender does when there is no data. If nothing `recv` will block waiting for new data. If sender closes tcp connection then respective error should be reported by `recv` and loop should be ended.

If you are fetching data form some HTTP server then most probably server assumes that client will close connection. Server just waits for next request.

Note also that depending on `SOCKET` configuration `recv` can be blocking or not. So depending on that `recv` may return `0` on success when in fact there will be new data in future.

Comment: yes I did fix that error but the program is is not exiting when the file is downloaded

Comment: how sender behaves? What is the other side?

Comment: @MarekR: Good points overall, however `recv` on a non-blocking socket should not return `0`, it should return `-EWOULDBLOCK` (I forget whether that's directly in the return value, or arbitrary negative return value and `EWOULDBLOCK` in `errno`).  Either way, `0` can only occur when reading to the end of a (half-)closed source.

Comment: The sender is netcat `nc -nvlp < port` and i also tested with python sockets and it does not seem to terminate,  isn't there a function end the connection other than `closesocket` and `WSACleanup` because i already tried them and they do not solve this issue

Comment: I'm not familiar with this tool, apparently it doesn't close connection when end of file is reached.

Comment: Note that OP seems to have applied at least one of your recommended fixes to the code in the question, thereby at least partially invalidating your answer.